# What is the difference between threo/erythro ephedrine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

I want to know how to easily make the difference or just understand the importance of stereocenters of ephedrine ?

Comment: Are you asking about how the chemical is processed by the human body?

Comment: I was asking about ephedrines  stereochemistry part. thank you Martin

Answer (score 3):

**1.Ephedrine exhibits optical isomerism and has two chiral centres, giving rise to four stereo isomers. By convention, the pair of enantiomers with the stereochemistry (1R,2S and 1S,2R) is designated ephedrine, while the pair of enantiomers with the stereochemistry (1R,2R and 1S,2S) is called pseudoephedrine.**
Source :https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephedrine

2. Again in order to distinguish threo from erythro.. Just memorize the word :TOES =Threo - Opposite Erythro - Same
   e. g., [image: Threo - Erythro]

Comment: hi!( 1R 2S and 1S2R),( 1R2R 1S2S)  are enantiomers,right? @user16976

Comment: (1R,2S and 1S,2R)is a pair of enantiomers and (1R,2R and 1S,2S)is another pair of enantiomers.

Comment: Please blockquote any text that you take directly from the source.  Thanks!